# reading a file and output to http

Tags: node.js

How do I join these to scripts into one as what I have done does not work. I think it is the callbacks that I am getting messed up.

With this code I am able to output text to my browser.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

---

With this code I am able to read a text file and log it to the console.

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

---

BUT THIS wont work together, WHY?????????????????
Thanks for the help.

```
   var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {

       fs = require('fs')
       fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
         if (err) {
           return console.log(err);
         }
         console.log(data);
         res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
         res.end('Hello World\n');
    });


    }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return your response AFTER your `readFile` finishes.  You do this by writing the response in the completion callback of `readFile` e.g.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
         if (err) {
           return console.log(err);
         }

         console.log(data);
         res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
         res.end(data);
    });

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```